# Automatic Logout the User after "X" time in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I need to logout the user in SharePoint 2013 after x amount of inactive time. I tried these options:

- Modify the  node with the timeout attribute.
- Run some PowerShell code to modify the LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow, FormsTokenLifetime and UseSessionCookies.
- Build a custom Global.ajax.cs to subscribe to the SessionSecurityTokenReceived Event.
- Modify the setting "Security validation expires" in Central Administration.

Neither of this solution just mentioned solve the problem, the user continue logged in the site after X amount of time.

The web application is using FBA with Membership.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If all of that failed, why not just add Javascript to the master page that uses setTimeOut() to redirect the user to the logout page after 20 minutes?  By default, this page is at `/_layouts/SignOut.aspx` but your FBA may have specified a different one.

Comment: Yes, but that solution only works when the user leaves the browser with the page open. I need to finish his/her session.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If the browser closes, the session should terminate automatically.  Is there code or something that you are attempting to run at the end of the session?

Comment: No, I don't use code to finish the session.